# RoR Redis subscription rspec stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm working on finding a stub for:

```
 @redis.subscribe(key) do |on|
   on.message do |channel, message|
      handle_message(message)
   end
 end
```

However I am unsure what type of object `on` is? How can we iterate on two fields channel, and message without a `.each` block? This seems to be a pretty common chunk of code if anyone had any examples for some unit tests.

Comment: add `puts on` inside your loop and see what you get

Comment: @dbugger Yes normally I would agree however I am working on an application that takes moving mountains to run locally, I was hoping theres some documentation I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah so here is what the function looks like and how to stub it.

```
def message
  yield('channel', 'message')
end

allow(on).to receive(:message).and_yield(channel, msg)
```